# get unique ID's of rows in php foreach loop for JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Good Afternoon,

I have 3 foreach loops on my page, the first gets the teams, the second gets each person in the team, and the third gets each unique reference to a task that the agent has completed. I have collected this data and it is being displayed fine. I now want to add some JQuery to it so it will hide the agents and references unless the relevant team or agent is clicked on. 
So if I load the page everything will be hidden apart from the teams, when I click on a team it will show the agents, when I click on an agent it will show the references.

I am having trouble assigning unique ID's to each row and finding those in the JQuery script.

Here is my code...

```
<?php if($aForm['sTaskType'] !== 'CP' ){?>
    <table style="width: 95%">
        <tr>
                <th>Area</th>
                <th>Pass</th>
                <th>Pass with feedback</th>
                <th>Fail with Minors</th>
                <th>Fail with Majors</th>
        </tr>

<?php  foreach ($aQualityTeamResults AS $iBusinessStreamId => $aTeamData) { 
$aQualityAgentResults = $oRadiusQualityFns->GetQualityAgentResults($sDateFrom, $sDateTo, $sTaskType, $aTeamData['iBusinessStreamId']);?>

        <tbody>
        <tr class="TeamClick<?php echo $aTeamData['iBusinessStreamId'];?>">
            <td><?php echo $aTeamData['sBusinessStream']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aTeamData['Pass']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aTeamData['Pass with Feedback']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aTeamData['Fail with Minors']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aTeamData['Fail with Majors']?></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>


            <?php  foreach ($aQualityAgentResults AS $iUserId => $aAgentData) { 
            $aQualityPropertyResults = $oRadiusQualityFns->GetQualityPropertyResults($sDateFrom, $sDateTo, $sTaskType, $aAgentData['iBusinessStreamId'], $aAgentData['Agent']);
            ?>
            <tbody>
            <tr  class="Agent<?php echo $iUserId]?>">
            <td><?php echo $oRadiusUser->Get_User_Name($aAgentData['Agent']);?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aAgentData['Pass'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aAgentData['Pass with Feedback'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aAgentData['Fail with Minors'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aAgentData['Fail with Majors'];?></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>

                <?php  foreach ($aQualityPropertyResults AS $iUserId => $aPropertyData) { ?>
                <tbody>
                <tr class="Property<?php echo $aPropertyData['iUserId'];?>">
                <td colspan="2"><a href="<?echo $sPage?>?sPostPropertyCode=<?php echo $aPropertyData['sPropertyCode'];?>&sPostTaskType=<?php echo $aPropertyData['sTaskType'];?>&iPostUserId=<?php echo $iUserId;?>"><font color="black"><?php echo $aPropertyData['sPropertyCode']?></font></a></td>
                <td colspan="3"><?php echo $aPropertyData['Result']?></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
<?php 

                }
        }
}
?>  

</table>
```

I have given each of the rows a unique class by adding in the unique identifier from the database. I just dont know how to find these within the Jquery script.

EDIT:

Maybe not explained myself properly, I would like help with how to set up this script but obviously a lot better.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >

        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.Agent').hide;
        $('.Property').hide;

        $(document).on('click','.TeamClick',function(){
            $('.Agent').toggle('show');
            $('.Property').toggle('show');

        });  
    });


</script>
```

But in this case it will show/hide all of the rows as they will all have the same id's, whereas now I have added on the unique id on the end with the php code in the class, I dont know how to call those as they all are called different classes. 
So if I click on TeamClick1, it shows the actual rows for that team (Agent1), and not all of them. but obviously I cant type out all of the unique id's I just dont know how to get them from the php in JQuery.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Agent').hide;
    $('.Property').hide;

    $(document).on('click','.TeamClick(UNIQUE ID)',function(){
        $('.Agent(UNIQUE ID)').toggle('show');
        $('.Property(UNIQUE ID)').toggle('show');

    });  
});
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Can you setup a jsFiddle with a demo of what you wish to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am hasty but it is like this

```
<?php if($aForm['sTaskType'] !== 'CP' ){?>
    <table style="width: 95%">
        <tr>
                <th>Area</th>
                <th>Pass</th>
                <th>Pass with feedback</th>
                <th>Fail with Minors</th>
                <th>Fail with Majors</th>
        </tr>

<?php  foreach ($aQualityTeamResults AS $iBusinessStreamId => $aTeamData) { 
$aQualityAgentResults = $oRadiusQualityFns->GetQualityAgentResults($sDateFrom, $sDateTo, $sTaskType, $aTeamData['iBusinessStreamId']);?>

        <tbody>
        <tr class="TeamClick<?php echo $iBusinessStreamId;?>">
            <td><?php echo $aTeamData['sBusinessStream']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aTeamData['Pass']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aTeamData['Pass with Feedback']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aTeamData['Fail with Minors']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aTeamData['Fail with Majors']?></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>


            <?php  foreach ($aQualityAgentResults AS $iUserId => $aAgentData) { 
            $aQualityPropertyResults = $oRadiusQualityFns->GetQualityPropertyResults($sDateFrom, $sDateTo, $sTaskType, $aAgentData['iBusinessStreamId'], $aAgentData['Agent']);
            ?>
            <tbody>
            <tr  class="Agent<?php echo $iUserId; ?>">
            <td><?php echo $oRadiusUser->Get_User_Name($aAgentData['Agent']);?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aAgentData['Pass'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aAgentData['Pass with Feedback'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aAgentData['Fail with Minors'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $aAgentData['Fail with Majors'];?></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>

                <?php  foreach ($aQualityPropertyResults AS $iUserId2 => $aPropertyData) { ?>
                <tbody>
                <tr class="Property<?php echo $iUserId2 ;?>">
                <td colspan="2"><a href="<?echo $sPage?>?sPostPropertyCode=<?php echo $aPropertyData['sPropertyCode'];?>&sPostTaskType=<?php echo $aPropertyData['sTaskType'];?>&iPostUserId=<?php echo $iUserId;?>"><font color="black"><?php echo $aPropertyData['sPropertyCode']?></font></a></td>
                <td colspan="3"><?php echo $aPropertyData['Result']?></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
<?php 

                }
        }
}
?>  

</table>
```

I'm putting the identifiers in classes, but if you want put in IDs you can, is the same thing, like this `id="<?php ... ?>"`